# Can't retract my delete vote

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

Yesterday I came across what appeared to be a zero-effort homework question, so I down- and close-voted the question, and also voted to delete after it was closed. A while later the person asking the question actually added their code, and while it's still just a mediocre question, I consider it good enough to deserve an answer, so I voted to re-open it and removed my downvote.

So far, so good. However, when I tried to also retract my delete vote I got a popup asking me (again) if I wanted to vote to delete the post. I expected the link to behave like the link for a close vote, allowing me to retract the vote I cast before. Is this difference in behavior intentional, and if so, what is the reasoning behind it? Shouldn't my delete vote at least be auto-removed when I vote to re-open the question?

Not sure if this is a bug, a missing feature, or undesired altogether, so I'm tagging the question [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) for the time being.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a bug and was never a feature. If the post isn't worth deleting, then no one is going to cast more votes to delete it, so don't worry<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> - if you still do, flag it for mod attention wording the reason similar to "could you delete and undelete the post so as to clear my delete vote on it". Though I have no idea what the response is going to be, an apocalypse shouldn't occur.

Comment: If there are multiple delete votes, the removal of one's vote without affecting the other votes seems not possible, even for a moderator.

Comment: @Cœur But moderators have the authority to unilaterally decide whether something's delete-worthy and so to use this hack if they consider it to not be delete-worthy even if there are other delete votes.

Comment: FWIW while moderators do have that power, there's a lot of precedent not to overrule the community in non-exceptional cases, so moderators are not likely to go around deleting/undeleting content willy nilly; they will likely take the position that it's not harming anything, and if it does end up getting deleted due to that, *then* you can flag it or ask on Meta to get it undeleted. Keep in mind that you can cast an undelete vote even after deleting a question with your delete vote, though.