# I suggested a tag synonym, but now I'd like to remove it

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

I suggested an existing less used tag synonym for a more used tag, but upon further reflection, I shouldn't have.

Is there anyway to remove it?

Comment: In the normal flow of things the syn suggestion is removed when it reaches a vote count of -2 (or becomes active at a count of 4) but until then stays pending. It's gone now though.

Comment: Somehow related: [Revoke tag synonym suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258008/1983854)

Comment: Somehow related: [how to remove a delete vote...?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314311/cant-retract-my-delete-vote) (hint: not possible)